# Convert HTML to json

Tags: php

```
<div id="category">
<div>
<div>
<h4>Main Cat</h4>
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">sub 01
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">sub 02
      </a>
    </li>
<li>
      <a href="#">sub 03
      </a>
    </li>
<li>
      <a href="#">sub 04
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        sub 05
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        sub 06
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<h4>Main Cat 2</h4>
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">sub 01
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">sub 02
      </a>
    </li>
<li>
      <a href="#">sub 03
      </a>
    </li>
<li>
      <a href="#">sub 04
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        sub 05
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        sub 06
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<h4>Main Cat 3</h4>
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">sub 01
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">sub 02
      </a>
    </li>
<li>
      <a href="#">sub 03
      </a>
    </li>
<li>
      <a href="#">sub 04
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        sub 05
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        sub 06
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div

    foreach($html->find('div[id="category"] > div') as $ul){
     foreach($ul->find('div') as $div) {
           $product = array();
           $product['h4'] = $div->find('h4')[0]->innertext;
           forreach($div->find('ul li') as $li) {
              $product['name'] = strip_tags(trim(preg_replace('/\s*\      
 ([^)]*\)/', '', $li->find('a')[0]->innertext)),'</span>');
            }
           $data['products'][] = $product;
   }
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Complete code is there, I want to make JSON from with these HTML codes, please help above code is only returning me last record of each UL, I don't know where I am putting wrong., please help me someone to get fixed.

Comment: Could you please tell me the JSON format ?eg.  "<DIV id="category">"

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<?php
foreach($html->find('div[id="category"] > div') as $ul){
  foreach($ul->find('div') as $div) {
    $product = array();
    $product['h4'] = $div->find('h4')[0]->innertext;
    foreach($div->find('ul li') as $key => $li) {
      $product['name'][] = strip_tags(trim(preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $li->find('a')[0]->innertext)),'</span>');
    }
    $data['products'][] = $product;
  }
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

You had a `forreach` instead of a `foreach` and you needed to add a new element to the `product['name']` array instead of overwriting it.

`$product['name'][]` instead of `$product['name']`.

Output:

```
{  
   "products":[  
      {  
         "h4":"Main Cat",
         "name":[  
            "sub 01",
            "sub 02",
            "sub 03",
            "sub 04",
            "sub 05",
            "sub 06"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "h4":"Main Cat 2",
         "name":[  
            "sub 01",
            "sub 02",
            "sub 03",
            "sub 04",
            "sub 05",
            "sub 06"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "h4":"Main Cat 3",
         "name":[  
            "sub 01",
            "sub 02",
            "sub 03",
            "sub 04",
            "sub 05",
            "sub 06"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i havent tried this it but looking at your

Instead of:

```
forreach($div->find('ul li') as $li) 
{
    $product['name'] = strip_tags(trim(preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $li->find('a')[0]->innertext)),'</span>');
}
```

Should it be like this?

```
forreach($div->find('ul') as $li) 
{
    forreach($li->find('ul') as $ul) 
    {
       // do somehting
    }
}
```

BTW its almost 3 years the last time i code using php.. but analyze and check your code